# Testing if a combined variable name exists

Tags: php, parsing, variables

I am sure this has been asked 100 times but cannot find the form of words to get at the answer either here or on Google.

I have a variable number of messages. They arrive as

```
$_GET['message1']; $_GET['message2']; $_GET['messageX']; etc
```

where X can be 1 to 100.

I need to test if they exist and then push them out to a DB. I tried

```
$i=1;
while (isset(parse_str("message$i"))) 
{
    echo parse_str("output=message$i");
    echo "<h1>This is test $output </h1>";
$i++;
}
```

which does not work. I thought the middle part worked but just re-tested and that is wrong too.

I am new to `parse_str()`. I thought I understood it and I understand the problem (it is a void function so cannot be used as a test) but cannot work out a solution for getting through the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_str` parses a string. What do you expect in a string `"message$i"`?

If you're sure that all your messages come from `$_GET`, use `$_GET`:

```
$i = 1;
while (isset($_GET['message' . $i])) {
    echo $_GET['message' . $i];
    $i++;
}
```

But obviously for storing such data, arrays are move convenient.

Comment: OMG thank you that looks so obvious. `parse_str` does allow you to form a variable name I think (pretty sure I managed to create $test$i  (eg $test7="Hello" and it worked but cannot remember how I did it). Does not matter if this works that is 100% fine and yes it should be an array but ... BRB... yep 100% works. That is another hour of my life completely wasted. That was so so so obvious. Thanks a million.